# Is it possible to run three phase motor with single phase supply? How?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have rubber mixer machine that motor need three phase supply. Unfortunately I only have single phase supply. I heard a rumor that three phase motor can be run with single phase supply. So, pls guy here help me out of this problem. Your answer is so greatful in advance.

Comment: There are ways - rotary phase converters, static phase converters, and today affordable inverter drives power derated according to the manual for single-phase input.  Or also just replacing the motor.  But this is a *usage* rather than *design* question so it is considered off-topic here.  Try a home machine shop type forum, they deal with this all the time.

Comment: There is a piece of equipment you can purchase to do this. It is a variable frequency drive, or VFD. VFD is basically just another word for what Chris called an "inverter drive." Most of them will probably require 220-250 VAC single-phase input, but I have seen a few for smaller three phase motors that can run from 120VAC single-phase.

Comment: Where can I get VFD and how to do it. Guy got any idea that I can reference it.

Comment: @hacker .world
Danfoss Drives has excellent frequency inverters.

Comment: Google of vfd gives a good start.... they come with installation instructions and the few i've looked at those could be downloaded if you need an idea of the work involved.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I view the proper selection of equipment to solve this problem as an engineering problem. As AVD application engineer, I was paid to advise customers and sales personnel on dealing with this type of problem for many years. Granted, the OP is unlikely to be an industrial customer, but we aren't answering questions in a paid professional capacity either.

Comment: @CharlesCowie *designing* a VFD would be on topic here.  *Using* or *selecting* one would not - that's a role for industrial and hobby machinist sites.

Answer (score 3):

A variable-frequency drive (VFD) should be preferred over the Steinmetz connection. The Steinmetz connection only allows the motor to work at about 70% of its rated power and produce 20% to 30% of the rated starting torque. I suspect that a rubber mixer will not tolerate that limitation.

A VFD of a current design from a reputable manufacturer will allow most motors to work at full power and produce rated starting torque. Most manufacturers have both variable torque / standard duty models and constant torque / heavy duty models. For a rubber mixer, you should buy the heavy duty model. Most of the well-known international manufacturers of industrial electrical equipment make VFDs.

Single-phase input, three-phase output are only widely available for 230 volt motors rated up to about 3 Hp (2.2 kW). Larger sizes are available, but more difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Steinmetz Circuit:

[image]

The capacitor will provide a phase shift that will generate a (non-symmetrical) rotating magnetic field.

Comment: Shown configuration is Delta. Star and half-star work equally well.
Read https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetzschaltung for explanation. Unfortunately there is no english version of this page.

Comment: Of course you can also use a frequency inverter, or other techniques, but which are often more expensive.

Comment: This is far short of a useful answer.  The reason questions like this get closed is that they are application questions, not design questions.  To be a useful answer you would have to go through the details of calculating the required capacitance *from an end user's perspective rather than an engineer's and then get into all the issues of practical implementation*.  User-oriented sites sometimes attempt to do that, typically along with discussing the tradeoffs which you have entirely neglected to mention.